# Google Datastore unable to connect inside Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Docker Compose file which runs the Google Datastore emulator:

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator

```
version: '3'
services:

  database:
    image: google/cloud-sdk
    command: gcloud beta emulators datastore start --host-port 0.0.0.0:8000 --project emulator --store-on-disk
    ports:
      - 8000:8000

  backend:
    build: ./backend
    command: npm run start:dev
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST: backend:8000
      DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID: emulator
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/usr/src/app:rw
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

I have a NodeJS backend which follows the NodeJS datastore example:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/datastore/app.js

```
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
const datastore = Datastore();
const query = datastore.createQuery('visit');
datastore.runQuery(query);
```

When I run the script locally it works:

```
npm start
```

However when I run with Docker Compose the NodeJS example hangs, without showing any error message:

```
docker-compose up
```

In both examples I can see the 'Ok' message by visiting:

```
http://localhost:8000
```

So I know the datastore instance is running correctly. But it hangs when I got the endpoint at:

http://localhost:8080/items

Why is it hanging? Is it trying to connect to a live project? I want to run a completely siloed Docker container without connecting to a live Google Cloud Project.

Full project source is here:

https://github.com/kmturley/appengine-datastore-nest-angular

Comment: I was not able to replicate the issue using:
https://github.com/kmturley/appengine-datastore-nest-angular

The ```docker-compose up ``` command worked as expected. Connections to: http://localhost:8000, http://localhost:8080, http://localhost:4200 all work as expected.

Comment: Sorry when hitting the API endpoint http://localhost:8080/items which is actually querying the datastore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken, when you're specifying environment variables for your backend you should say that emulator address is `database:8000` instead of `backend:8000`:

```
environment:
      DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST: database:8000
```

Apart from that the config seems too be fine. Let me know if that helps